# Compile part of sass or scss file

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have wrote a large main.scss file with variables and mixins to style many pages of my website, I want to know if there is a way to compile different files for the different pages and these files just include the styles for the pages. For ex:

I have main.scss file which contains styles for index.php, about.php, and list.php, rather than all these php files share the same compiled main.css, I want the sass/compass compiler to compile different files for these pages.

Or there is another technique to accomplish this.

Please advice,

Thanx,

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for this?  Having multiple CSS files for a single website is considered undesirable for performance reasons.

Comment: yes there is, when I'm using specific css styles in specific pages (not all the pages) and these pages are big, so it's better for performance not to load all the styles that i'll not use.

Comment: Did you actually *test* this?  I don't doubt that fewer styles result in better performance, but this sounds like a micro-optimization.  If your page is large enough that the smaller CSS makes a noticeable impact, one wonders why you're serving such a large document in the first place.

Comment: I'm working on a very large platform with 10,000,000 users so any small thing regarding optimization and performance matters, any advice is welcome.

Comment: You're confused.  A small CSS file is only going to boost rendering speeds (and a marginal improvement at that), the number of users you have is irrelevant for this type of performance gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Split your main.scss into multiple files. For example scaffolding.scss, nav.scss, button.scss etc.
2. Create index.scss, about.scss and list.scss. In each of these files import scaffolding.scss, nav.scss and other files you need for the specific page

Example

scaffolding.scss:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

nav.scss:

```
nav {
    color: pink;
}
```

button.scss:

```
input[type=button] {
    width: 2em;
}
```

---

index.scss:

```
@import "scaffolding";
@import "nav";
```

about.scss:

```
@import "scaffolding";
@import "nav";
```

list.scss:

```
@import "scaffolding";
@import "button";
```

---

If you are concerned about performance, it could still be a good choice to have all your css in one file since it will only be downloaded the first time, the next time it will be loaded from the cache.

Comment: thanx for your advice, but I was thinking that would be special tags or @include to indicate where the following styles will be compiled. So I'll still have the same main.scss with tags inside it that surround the styles and when compiling main.scss would compile to scaffolding.css, nav.css, buttons.css

Comment: I think what you wan't cannot be done. Sass doesn't know it's being called from what file. What you can do is specify the sass file to be used on different pages. And from that sass file you structure which selector to be used by the page.